# "match_parent" sometimes behaves incorrectly since Android SDK version 18

Tags: android, android-layout

I found a weird behavior when playing with the StickyGridHeaders library. Just like any list item, the library allows us to use any layout as the header view. Here is my header view layout definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#228B22"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#FF8C00"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="#00FFFF" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The header view is pretty simple: a TextView for title, and a separator beneath.

However, when debugging in my device (running 4.4.2 KitKat), the header looks strange. I don't have enough reputation to post images, please [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3E_dT4tRjnPSmJFV2o5bmJXUkk/edit?usp=sharing) to see the image (hosted in Google Drive).

I added background colors to the layout to illustrate the problem. In the screenshot, header "A" is sticky, and is shown correctly. However, for non-sticky headers like "B" and "C", you can see the width of the title and the separator are not correct. Both the width of TextView and the FrameLayout are set to "match_parent" in the xml file, yet in the screenshot, the TextView of the non-sticky headers are displayed as if they are set to "wrap_content". Even more weird is the separator - I tried using different text for the title, and it turns out that the width of the separator aligns perfectly with the (incorrect) width of the TextView above it, not the parent's available width!

At first I thought I wrote the layout incorrectly. Then I found the problem persists when I copy the library examples to the new project. So I turned my eye to the SDK version, and tried changing the target SDK version to 17. To my surprise, everything looks correctly. [(Click here for screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3E_dT4tRjnPVDVGUmRxVkdvMjA/edit?usp=sharing)

Then I bump the target SDK version to 18 and the problem comes again.

I understand that the layout can be different in different SDK version, but I don't get the idea why "match_parent" can behave differently in newer SDK version.

Comment: have you tried to change this `/>` in the end of your textview by this: `</TextView>` ??

Comment: or change the `match_parent` to `fill_parent` ?

Comment: what for? it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if anyone encountered the same issue like me, but I finally found out what's wrong: **The StickyGridHeaders library in the maven repository DOESN'T match the one on Github.** The former one should be a old version because the problem went away after I replaced the library with the one on Github.